# Why does Logic App Standard Plan have missing connection trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Standard Plan Logic App. When I go into workflow >> add >> designer to create an action I want to select `SQL Server >> When an item is created`. I am no longer able to see any triggers for it. When I created a similar logic app using consumption this option was present. Has something changed that would not allow for this connector in the Standard Plan? I can see a lot of connectors missing between consumption and standard.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the firewall restricting access to all connector options.

***Firewall access for connections.**
If you use a firewall that limits traffic, and your logic app workflows need to communicate through that firewall, you have to set up your firewall to allow access for both the inbound and outbound IP addresses used by the Logic Apps service or runtime in the Azure region where your logic app workflows exist. If your workflows also use managed connectors, such as the Office 365 Outlook connector or SQL connector, or use custom connectors, your firewall also needs to allow access for all the managed connector outbound IP addresses in your logic app's Azure region. For more information, review Firewall configuration.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list